# How to show custom (checkbox) field value in admin post list?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, columns

I have a custom post type for products and a custom meta checkbox field for 'Sold'. How can I show the Sold status in a column on the Products edit list and make it sortable (so it would sort all the sold items together) or filter them by the Sold status?

Answer (score 3):

i did something similar with some radio buttons and a special taxonomy.  i worked almost exclusively from the following 2 tutorials:

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/expand-the-wordpress-quick-edit-menu
http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html

though i was working with a taxonomy, the scribu tutorial actually links to another scribu tutorial on sorting by meta, which is more in-line w/ the OP's question:

http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html

Comment: Useful, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: the OP asked how to add meta information to the edit list?  the first article covers that.  the second article covers how to make columns sortable, though i'd agree that the article it links to: custom sortable columns is more appropriate.  so i'll amend my answer.

Comment: I interpreted that the returned meta value should also be given a checkbox for quick edit. Getting a post_meta does not set the checkbox to true also. It validates the value but you must set the checkbox value to 'checked'. The example provides a simple db lookup, whereas a checbox holds a value that is serialized in php

Comment: ok, i didn't get that.  there are only 2 sentences to the question and the OP seems gone so i guess we'll never know exactly what he was going for.  i didn't feel like putting a lot of effort into answering a question that didn't appear to show alot of effort.